# Probability of picking the same path twice in a fully connected graph

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory

I have a fully connected graph $G$ with $n$ vertices. I pick at random a path composed of three intermediate nodes from $A$ to $B$ (e.g., $A \rightarrow X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z \rightarrow B$). Next, I also pick a random path between $C$ and $B$, also composed of three intermediate nodes. What is the probability that I select exactly the same path?

Comment: Since the graph is complete, this is the same as the probability of choosing the exact same sequence $\{A,X,Y,Z,B\}$. If $A \ne C$ the probability is zero, otherwise it is $1/M$ where $M$ is the number of sequences $X,Y,Z$ such that $\{X,Y,Z\} \subset \{1,\ldots m\}$ and $m$ is $n, n-1$ or $n-2$, depending on whether cycles are allowed or not and on whether $A \ne B$ or not. Excluding the initial node from the path (to avoid the trivial case) doesn't change the answer much.